# Budgeting app that automatically monitors credit card account

Tags: android, monitoring, finance

It seems like there are many Android apps for personal finance/budgeting, but all the ones I've seen require to manually enter every transaction into your phone.

Is there an app that will access the transaction data in my credit card account, and fetch transactions in real time from there, without any extra work from me?

Open source preferred but not necessary.

Comment: I doubt that for credit cards, but be welcome to check my [Home-Banking](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/finance_banking) app list. For recommendations, there might be a few more details required – as many such apps depend on a given bank institute or at least country/region.